# How to find a "central" anchor-point in a point-set/2D-shape?

Tags: algorithm, set, 2d

[image: Point-Set]

The center-coordinates of the 2D-voxels represent a 2D-point-set. Using these coordinates, the red dot in the picture refers to the (approximate) center of mass/gravity, i.e. the mean of all coordinates. Ignore the different grayvalues, though they coincidentally provide for a slightly better visibility of the 2D voxels :-)

The green dot (roughly) is what I would like to get, but how (?), in a principled manner (?). So essentially we have a connected set in 2D voxel-space or alternatively a set of 2D-points, integer coordinates can be assumed, if it helps. I'd like to determine a point, which is "central" with respect to the shape, but definitely on the shape, i.e. part of the set.

Pseudocode and/or C/C++ welcome :-)

Update: If the structure was thicker, I'd actually like the green point to be somewhat central rather than on the contour.

Comment: Maybe you want the point of the shape with the least mean squared distance to all the other points of the shape?

Comment: @Niklas: Sounds very good. Can I do that in significantly less than O(N^2) ?

Comment: You can do all-pairs furthest points in n log n. That gives you the point with the least maximum distance to any of the other points. Not sure about mean distance to all points. Doesn't sound impossible, maybe you can consult Google for hints.

Comment: I meant compute the furthest point for every point in the set (all-pairs doesn't male sense)

Comment: You can probably also compute the point with minimum mean manhattan distance in O(n log n) because the coordinates can be processed separately here (the problem reduces to a few simple range queries for every point)

Answer (score 0):

here is solution that can find the green point in `O(N)` :-

```
Find mean (xm,ym)

Suppose (xm+a),(ym+b) is a point in the dataset

E(xi,yi) = sum of squared distances of all points from (xi,yi)

E(xm,ym) = k   because it is the mean.

E(xm+a,ym+b) = summation => (xi-(xm+a))^2 + (yi-(ym+b))^2

             = summation => ((xi-xm)-a)^2 + ((yi-ym)-b)^2

             = summation => (xi-xm)^2 + (yi-ym)^2 + a^2 + b^2 - 2a*(xi-xm) - 2b*(yi-ym)

             = summation => (xi-xm)^2 + (yi-ym)^2 + summation => a^2 + b^2 +.....

   summation => (xi-xm)^2 + (yi-ym)^2 = E(xm,ym) = k

Hence

E(a,b) = summation => a^2 + b^2 - 2a*(xi-xm) - 2b*(yi-ym)

as a,b are constant in summation

E(a,b) = (a^2+b^2)*N - 2a*(summation=>(xi-xm)) - 2b*(summation=>(yi-ym))

summation=>(xi-xm) = 0
summation=>(y1-ym) = 0

E(a,b) = a^2 + b^2

Now to get green point which will minimize E(a,b)

a = xk-xm
b = yk-ym 

find (xp,yp)=>minimum{E(a,b)}  among all (xk,yk)

summation=>(xi-xm) and summation=>(yi-ym) can be found in O(N) after finding mean

hence E(a,b) can be found in O(1) and (xp,yp) in O(N)
```

Comment: Very intriguing, but isn't summation=>(xi-xm) = 0, with xm = 1/N * summation->(xi) and summation=>(xi-xm) = -N*xm + summation=>(xi). I really like the derivation though (!). It seems that your approach simply finds the closest point to the mean, right? ...which is not a bad solution...

Comment: @Dr.D Good observation there (Didnt expect it to simplify so much). Yes the formula suggests that it finds the point closest to the mean and any such point will minimize the mean squared distances.

Comment: @Dr.D You can have multiple points like that so can find median of them on x co-ordinate or y co-ordinate to get one central point